# Can i add property to a BPEL in active composite without redeploy through WLST

Tags: oracle, web-services, soa, wlst

I want to add **bpel.config.auditLevel** property to my SOA Web Services but because they are many and because of that, i need to find a way to do this through **Web Logic Script Tool(WLST)** with simple Jython script. Ive searched in the entire internet with no luck... Maybe this is not possible or i don't know.

Ive find a **WLST** command called **setWebServiceClientStubProperty()** but i'm not so sure is that the one i need and there is no examples how to use it soa web services.

Can any one help me with this ?

Thank in advance!
D.T.

Comment: hey @TheMulti, don't forget to accept the answer that helped : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
Connect(USERNAME, PWD, URL)
custom()
cd('oracle.soa.config')
redirect('NULL','false')
list = ls(returnMap='true')
redirect('NULL','true')
for composite in list:
  compositeObject = ObjectName(composite)
  if compositeObject.getKeyProperty('j2eeType') == 'SCAComposite':
    if compositeObject.getKeyProperty('name') == 'YOUCOMPOSITENAME':
        compositeProperties = mbs.getAttribute(compositeObject, 'Properties')
        compositeProperties[0].set('YOURAUDITLEVEL')
```